# Validating an input field on click of a button in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to make an input field as Required & Numeric-only by displaying just a star (*) next to it when the Add button is clicked next to the input field. Add button is not a submit button.

Would like to do this using Knockout extenders. Any reference to sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at Ko validation

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you go : https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

This is the best thing you can get to validate observables. :-)

Sample :

```
self.myObservable = ko.observable('').extend({ required: true });
```

They have very good api :-)